# how do i show the variable using popup in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

how do i show the recipe variable using pop up?
so i would like to display the return result in popup

this is my code

```
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

function DisplayRecipe({ searchResult }) {
  const { idMeal } = useParams();
  const recipe = searchResult.find((item) => item.idMeal === idMeal);
  console.log(recipe);
  return (
    <>
      {recipe.strMeal}
      <br />
      {recipe.strIngredient1}
      <br />
      Instructions
      <br />
      {recipe.strInstructions}
    </>
  );
}

export default DisplayRecipe;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "popup"?  You could simply do `alert("recipe is: " + JSON.stringify(recipe))`....that would be a "popup".

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use a package such as **react-modal** for showing recipe details in a modal.

Make a RecipeModal component:

```
import ReactModal from 'react-modal';

function RecipeModal({ isOpen, onRequestClose, recipe }) {
  return (
    <ReactModal isOpen={isOpen} onRequestClose={onRequestClose}>
     <div>
       {recipe && (
        <>
        {recipe.strMeal}
        <br />
        {recipe.strIngredient1}
        <br />
        Instructions
        <br />
        {recipe.strInstructions}
         </>
       )}
     </div>
    </ReactModal>
   );
}
export default RecipeModal;
```

Use above component in your DisplayRecipe component as below:

```
<RecipeModal isOpen={isModalOpen} onRequestClose={closeModal} recipe={recipe} />
```

You can decide when to open or close your modal in your DisplayRecipe component by storing modal state in component state:

```
const [isModalOpen, setIsModalOpen] = useState(false);

const openModal = () => setIsModalOpen(true);
const closeModal = () => setIsModalOpen(false);
```